# HTML to Java characters changes

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, utf-8

I'm populating a dropdown listbox in jsp with strings with characters like \u00e8. I will use the selected value of the dropdown to filter the display in a table with values retrieved from DB. However, when I send them back to servlet via request.getAttribute, its value changed. I used [org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeJava%28java.lang.String%29) and found that its value changed from \u00e8 to \u00C3\u00A8. The content type of the webpage is UTF-8. How can I have consistent characters for HTML and Java?

Sorry if I cannot put comments, accept answer, vote for comments as javascript in my workstation is disabled (which really sucks). I'll do them once I get home. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on my Multi-part file upload.

```
List formItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
            Iterator iter = formItems.iterator();

            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();

                String field = "";
                String value = "";
                if (item.isFormField()) {
                    try{
                        field=item.getFieldName();
                        value=item.getString("UTF-16");                  
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){                     
                    }
                }
```